# gdbus: is it safe to free signal argument right after signal emission

Tags: c, glib, gdbus

I created simple dbus service that emits signal with dynamically allocated data argument:

```
file_name = g_strdup("myfile");
...
...
g_signal_emit_by_name (object, "mysignal", file_name);
g_free(file_name);
```

In this case signal listeners may receive `file_name` string that was already destroyed.

So is it safe to free `file_name` right after `g_signal_emit_by_name` call or I should wait for a few seconds?
Or is there any other mechanism to free memory in such cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GSignal emission is synchronous, i.e. all the connected callbacks to a signal are run sequentially by `g_signal_emit()`, which will return control to you once all callbacks return. thus, it is safe to emit a signal and free the arguments of the signal after `g_signal_emit()` returns.

if you're using DBus then it's still safe: the data will be copied over to the receiving process(es), as it would be impossible to share it across process boundaries.

Comment: Do I need to free this data in the receiver?

Comment: it entirely depends on the API you use in the receiver.

Comment: typically it would be a bad idea to have data sent with g_signal_emit freed by receivers, since there could be multiple ones; better to handle it on the sender side.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the gdbus API in particular, but in general for this kind of usage, you want to make it the recipient's responsibility to free the storage. The only exceptions would be when the object is known to have a lifetime that will persist beyond the needs of the recipient (e.g. static storage) or the API handles copying data for you.

Comment: well, (as i said above) you can connect any number of receivers to the signal and you need to free the storage only once... so better to do it after g_signal_emit returns.